Lifting generators from a quotient group to the original group
Suppose $G$ is a finite group generated by $2$ elements, and $H$ is a quotient group of $G$. I want to ask whether the following holds.

If $H$ is cyclic, then any generator of it lifts to an element $a$ of $G$, such that there's a $b\in G$ such that $G=\langle a,b\rangle$; and if $H$ is generated by $2$ elements, then any set of two generators of $H$ lifts to two generators of $G$.

For $D_n$ and $Q_8$ I think it's OK. But I don't know how to prove it or any counterexample.

$H$ is quotient by what?

@julio_es_sui_glace $H$ is a quotient group of $G$

I am voting to reopen. The reason for closing it was that the question needs to be more focused, but in fact the two questions asked are just the first two cases of a single more general question, which I have answered below.

What is the one doing while voting for close it? Here is only one question if you know the basic group theory. I think the committee should be more focused while reading.

The answer to your question is yes. Using an elementary but clever counting argument, Gaschütz proved that if $N$ is a finite normal subgroup of a finitely generated group $G$, and $G$ can be generated by $d$ elements then, for any $g_1,\ldots,g_d \in G$ such that $G/N = \langle g_1N,\ldots,g_dN \rangle$, there exists $n_1,\ldots, n_d \in N$ such that $G = \langle g_1n_1,\ldots,g_dn_d \rangle$.
This is proved in the paper
W. Gaschütz, Zu einem von B.H. und H. Neumann gestellten Problem, Math. Nachr. 14
(1956), 249–252. MR 18:790b.
Unfortunately the journal volume is not particularly easy to access, and the paper is in German. So here is an outline of the proof.
Suppose that $N \unlhd G$ with $N$ finite and
$g_1, \ldots, g_d \in G$ with $G/N = \langle g_1 N, \ldots, g_d N \rangle$.
Since $N$ is finite and $G/N$ is finitely generated, the
set ${{\cal S}}$ of subgroups $H$ of $G$ with $HN=G$ is finite, because
each such subgroup is generated by elements $g_1 u_1, \ldots, g_d u_d$
with $u_i \in N$, together with a subgroup of $N$, and there are only
finitely many sequences $u_1,\ldots,u_d \in N$ and subgroups of $N$.
We claim that, for any $H \in {{\cal S}}$, the number $f(H)$ of $d$-tuples
$(u_1,\ldots,u_d)$ of elements of $N$ such that
$H = \langle g_1 u_1, \ldots, g_d u_d \rangle$ (which could be $0$)
is the same for any $d$-tuple $(g_1,\ldots,g_d)$ of elements of $G$ such that
$G/N = \langle g_1 N, \ldots, g_d N \rangle$.  So if $G$ can generated
by $d$ elements, then $f(G) > 0$ and the result follows.
We prove the claim by induction on $|H \cap N|$. We see easily that
the result holds with $f(H)=1$ when $H \cap N = 1$. For $H \cap N \ne 1$,
the number is $|H \cap N|^d - \sum_{K \in {{\cal S}}, K < H} f(K)$ which completes
the induction.
